# Spring cache EhCache | Data are not updated and deleted from cache

Tags: spring-boot, caching, ehcache, spring-cache

I start to learn Spring Cache abstraction. 
I use Spring boot, Spring Data Jpa, EhCache provider for this purpose.

My ehcache.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ehcache>
<ehcache>

    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100"
              eternal="false"
              timeToIdleSeconds="120"
              timeToLiveSeconds="120"
              overflowToDisk="true">
</defaultCache>

<cache name="teams"
       maxElementsInMemory="500"
       eternal="true"
       timeToIdleSeconds="0"
       timeToLiveSeconds="100"
       overflowToDisk="false">
</cache>
```

My service:

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "teams")
@Service
public class TeamService {
    @Autowired
    private TeamRepository teamRepository;
    @Cacheable
    public Team findById(long id) {
        return teamRepository.findById(id).get();
    }
    @Cacheable
    public List<Team> findAll() {
        return teamRepository.findAll();
    }
    @CachePut
    public Team save(Team team) {
        return teamRepository.save(team);
    }
    @CacheEvict
    public void delete(long id) {
        teamRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
public class TeamController {
    @Autowired
    private TeamService teamService;
    @GetMapping("/teams")
    public List<Team> getAll() {
        return teamService.findAll();
    }
    @GetMapping("/team/{id}")
    public Team getById(@PathVariable long id) {
        return teamService.findById(id);
    }
    @DeleteMapping("/team/{id}")
    public void delete(@PathVariable long id) {
        teamService.delete(id);
    }
    @PostMapping("/team")
    public Team save(@RequestBody Team team) {
        return teamService.save(team);
    }
}
```

I am performing requests to my controller...

When I perform getAll() method of the controller data are cached correctly and  then don't exucute query to database at next times. Then I update and delete data from the database using corresponding methods of my controller, which service methods are marked as @CachePut and @CacheEvict respectively and must refresh cache. Then I perform above getAll() method again and get the same response like at the first time but I want that it will be refreshed after performing delete and update requests.

What's I doing wrong or How I can get the desired result?.

Comment: I am having same issue. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

When you put @Cachable annotation on a method so all entries will be kept on cache added by default a name then the first cachable is different to second cachable, so if you want to work well you need to add a name that you want,  for example:

```
@Cachable("teams") 

@Cachable("teams") 

@CachePut("teams")

@CacheEvict(value="teams", allEntries=true)
```

You can get more information in this link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cache-tutorial

Perhaps a best solution would be this:

```
@Cachable("team") 

@Cachable("teams") 

@Caching(put = { 
    @CachePut(value="team"), 
    @CachePut(value="teams") })

@Caching(evict = { 
    @CacheEvict(value="team", allEntries=true), 
    @CacheEvict(value="teams", allEntries=true) })
```

Comment: I  have the @CacheConfig(cacheNames = "teams") annotation on the class level that similar to your approach. But yout approach with direct declaring at all methods I was trying  and it doesn't work too)

Comment: I updated my answer and please remove name on @CacheConfig. could you please try it?

Comment: Maybe, for this approach I need to define some "team" cache on my configuration, because I get java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find cache named 'team'

Comment: Oh right, you need create a cache config  more.. Just copy and paste the same aans change name...